# Table collapse issue in Edge explore

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

This line of code works good on different browsers except edge.

```html
  *<tbody id="cat_${cat.prefix}" class="table-responsive collapse";>*
```

In Edge explorer the spaces between rows very high and messed up when I click a row to collapse the body table. how can I fix this problem in edge?

Comment: You had just post a 1 line of code. I try to make a test in various browsers including MS Edge with code in this link. https://textuploader.com/dwf0u I am not able to produce the issue and code is working fine. It is possible that some other CSS class affecting the output in your table. You can try to check it. try to make a test with my code and check whether you are able to produce the issue or not. also try to post the picture of your output. It can give us more idea about the issue. you can also provide a working sample code.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Bootstrap-table-responsive-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nested table in Html page the tag  dose not work correctly in Edge browser, so we should change it to  tag.